# Make a simple web browser that would be able to display pages like "agar.io"

Tags: java

I have a simple web browser coded in java.

As you may know, the application can't display much.

For instance, google. It won't display the page the right way.

But that's not the problem I want to solve..

The problem is that it won't display pages like AGAR.io (don't misspell the "agar" word.. There's a Jeff the Killer jumpscare if you open this page : agor.io. So be careful :))

Here's the java code of the simple web browser:

```
package Gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.IDN;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Frame extends JFrame implements HyperlinkListener {
  private JTextField txtURL= new JTextField("");
  JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane();
  private JLabel lblStatus= new JLabel(" ");

  public Frame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel pnlURL = new JPanel();
    pnlURL.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pnlURL.add(new JLabel("URL: "), BorderLayout.WEST);
    pnlURL.add(txtURL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(pnlURL, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    getContentPane().add( ep, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    getContentPane().add(lblStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {
          String url = ae.getActionCommand().toLowerCase();
          if (url.startsWith("http://"))
            url = url.substring(7);
          ep.setPage("http://" + IDN.toASCII(url));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame.this, "Browser problem: " + e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    };
    txtURL.addActionListener(al);

    setSize(300, 300);
    setVisible(true);
  }
  public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent hle) {
    HyperlinkEvent.EventType evtype = hle.getEventType();
    if (evtype == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED)
      lblStatus.setText(hle.getURL().toString());
    else if (evtype == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.EXITED)
      lblStatus.setText(" ");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Frame();
  }
}
```

But the program can't display pages such as agar.io.
Agar.io is a page with a simple game that seems to not use flashplayer..
Is there a way of making it possible?